# SSIS data load from Oracle source is dramatically slow

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

In my SSIS project I need sync data between Oracle and MS SQL.

MS VS 2017 32bit

MS SQL Server 2017 64bit

OLEDB Connector 32bit

The speed is 30 rows per 1 sec

1. I deleted the target destinations and added just row counter. **The same result.**
2. I did the DataFlow Setup:
   DefaultBufferMaxRows = 1000000
   DefaultBufferSize = 104857600
   **The same result.**
3. I changed source SQL to:

   SELECT * FROM SourceTable ORDER BY LAST_UPDATE OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10000 ROWS ONLY

**The same result.**

I read a lot of but people ask how to optimise 100K rows / 3 sec. :)

P.S.
The same select work significantly faster from MS SQL Server:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([ORASA], 'SELECT * FROM SourceTable ORDER BY LAST_UPDATE OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10000 ROWS ONLY')
```

Comment: Assuming you run this in debug, do you have enough free memory on your DEV pc?

Comment: Why `select *`? Do you need every single column to be transported from Oracle to SQL Server over the wire?

Comment: 2. All columns are needed.

Comment: 1. Yes. It is debut mode but memory is enough. I deployed the project on server but the speed is the same.

Comment: Have you excluded there is no locking on the table ?

Comment: I think - no. I have the same problem with each table and there are not other processes in parallel.

Comment: Maybe, something should be added into OLEDB XML setup? There are default setup now.

Comment: _"Do not increase buffer size to the point where paging to disk starts to occur. Paging to disk hinders performance more than a buffer size that has not been optimized."_ Might be useful to reset to defaults and have a read through [Data Flow Performance Features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/data-flow-performance-features) to see how you could tune the connection.

Comment: I already read it. I don't understand why my performance is so slow and it is slow on the source side where is just reading from the table.